# Finding all eigen values of a special type of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I am to find all the eigenvalues of
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta & \beta & \beta \\
\beta & \alpha & \beta & \beta \\
\beta & \beta & \alpha & \beta \\
\beta & \beta & \beta & \alpha \\ 
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

---

My thoughts:

Sum of the elements of each row and column is $\alpha+3\beta$. Hence $\alpha+3\beta$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. How can I find the other eigenvalues?

---

Edit: Following @Gae. S. answer I have reached till here.

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is given by
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha-x & \beta & \beta & \beta \\
\beta & \alpha-x & \beta & \beta \\
\beta & \beta & \alpha-x & \beta \\
\beta & \beta & \beta & \alpha-x \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
which has 2 linear factors $(x-(\alpha+3\beta))$ and $(x-(\alpha-\beta))$

Answer (score 1):

$(1,-1,1,-1)^\top$ is a second eigenvector, and now that you have two roots of $\det(A-xI)$, computing the remaining two is trivial.

Comment: For finding the other two roots, should I  compute by brute force method the polynomial and then factor it by two linear polynomial corresponding to the known roots? and then proceed to compute the other root by solving the remaining quadratic equation?

Or is there some other small technique?

Comment: @Saikat That's what I was saying. There is a completely different way to obtain the result, but I'll leave it to someone else to figure out.

Comment: Can you please give me some hints? I will try thinking that way then.

Comment: @Saikat It revolves around the fact that if $v_i=1$ for all $i$, then $A=(\alpha-\beta)I+\beta vv^\top$.

Comment: If possible, can you please make me understand what is $v_i$?

Comment: I suppose that Gae. S. refers to the componentes of the vector $v$, I mean, $v = (1,\dots,1)^T$